# How can I refactor my data models to save memory in Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7

I've been hitting the soft memory limit and after much querying around here I found another person with the same issue and Nick Johnson identified that his models were too large.  How can I best refactor (i.e. break up) my models?

My current model has 37 properties with many lists.

```
class CurrentModel(db.Model): #currently has 37 properties
    mystring = db.StringProperty()
    mylist = db.ListProperty()
    ...
```

I was thinking maybe I could break it up as such - but would this save memory?

```
class ProposedModel(db.Model): #core properties
    mystring = db.StringProperty()
    ...
class ExtendedModel(db.Model): #extended properties
    parent_model = db.ReferenceProperty(ProposedModel)
    mylist = db.ListProperty()
    mylist1 = db.ListProperty()
    ...
```

Comment: It depends. What are your models actually doing? Whether it makes sense to split them, and how, will depend entirely on the queries and operations you need to perform.

Comment: My models have general descriptive properties, and it seems like I need them all for each uses; so in essence I'd be calling the extended model each time anyway.  If this saves no memory then I may as well keep them together.